# Python requests failing to decode text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using python requests and bs4 to scrape a website, but having some trouble with decoding (I think..)

```
logurl = 'https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=pwfone:login'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    }
    response = s.get(logurl)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8'
    print response.status_code 
    # return 200
    print (response.content)
    # returns: b'<html lang="en-us" xmlns:htmldb="http://htmldb.oracle.com">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />\r\n<title>Pay with Flash Login</title>\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/themes/SPhone/payback/theme_3_1.css" type="text/css" />\r\n\r\n<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/themes/SPhone/payback/ie.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/app_ui/css/Core.min.css?v=19.1.0.00.15" type="text/css" />\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/app_ui/css/Theme-Standard.min.css?v=19.1.0.00.15" type="text/css" />\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/libraries/jquery-ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui-apex.min.css?v=19.1.0.00.15" type="text/css" />\n\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/legacy_ui/css/5.0.min.css?v=19.1.0.00.15" type="text/css" />\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\n<script>\nvar apex_img_dir = "/i/", htmldb_Img_Dir = apex_img_dir;\n</script>\n<script src="/i/libraries/apex/minified/desktop_all.min.js?v=19.1.0.00.15"></script>\n<script src="wwv_flow.js_messages?p_app_id=1500&p_lang=en-us&p_version=19.1.0.00.15-94050580561"></script>\n<script src="/i/libraries/apex/minified/legacy_pre18.min.js?v=19.1.0.00.15"></script>\n<script src="/i/libraries/apex/minified/legacy_18.min.js?v=19.1.0.00.15"></script>\n<script src="/i/libraries/jquery-migrate/3.0.1/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js?v=19.1.0.00.15"></script>\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />\n\r\n</head>\r\n<body ><form action="wwv_flow.accept" method="post" name="wwv_flow" id="wwvFlowForm" novalidate  autocomplete="off">\n<input type="hidden" name="p_flow_id" value="1500" id="pFlowId" /><input type="hidden" name="p_flow_step_id" value="101" id="pFlowStepId" /><input type="hidden" name="p_instance" value="5488556618334" id="pInstance" /><input type="hidden" name="p_page_submission_id" value="119891457853323246540979814026507745288" id="pPageSubmissionId" /><input type="hidden" name="p_request" value="" id="pRequest" /><input type="hidden" name="p_reload_on_submit" value="A" id="pReloadOnSubmit" /><input type="hidden" value="119891457853323246540979814026507745288" id="pSalt" /><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="" id="t18PageBodyHead" width="80%" height="10%" align="center">\r\n<tr>\r\n<td align="center" id="t18Logo" valign="top"><br /></td>\r\n<td id="t18HeaderMiddle"  valign="top" width="100%"><br /></td>\r\n<td id="t18NavBar" valign="top"><br /><br /></td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</table>\r\n<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="" id="t18PageBody"  width="80%" height="70%" align="center">\r\n<tr id="t18tabscolor">\r\n<td valign="top" id="t18Tabs"  width="110%"></td></tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td valign="top" id="t18Tabs"></td></tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td valign="top"></td>\r\n<td class="t18PageRight"><br /></td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<td valign="top" id="t18ContentBody" height="100%" width="100%">\r\n<div id="t18Messages"><span id="APEX_SUCCESS_MESSAGE" data-template-id="165783099126927032_S" class="apex-page-success u-hidden"></span><span id="APEX_ERROR_MESSAGE" data-template-id="165783099126927032_E" class="apex-page-error u-hidden"></span></div>\r\n<div id="t18ContentMiddle"><table id="apex_layout_83448022784534430" border="0" class="formlayout"  role="presentation"><tr><td  align="right"><label for="P101_USERNAME" id="P101_USERNAME_LABEL" tabindex="999"><a class="t18OptionalLabelwithHelp" href="javascript:popupFieldHelp(\'83448127760534444\',\'5488556618334\')" tabindex="999">Username</a></label></td><td colspan="2"  align="left"><input type="text"  id="P101_USERNAME" name="P101_USERNAME" class="text_field&#x20;apex-item-text" value="" size="40" maxlength="100"  /></td></tr><tr><td  align="right"><label for="P101_PASSWORD" id="P101_PASSWORD_LABEL" tabindex="999"><a class="t18OptionalLabelwithHelp" href="javascript:popupFieldHelp(\'83448212820534447\',\'5488556618334\')" tabindex="999">Password</a></label></td><td  align="left"><input type="password" name="P101_PASSWORD" size="40" maxlength="100" value=""  id="P101_PASSWORD" class="password&#x20;apex-item-text"  onkeypress="return apex.submit({request:\'P101_PASSWORD\',submitIfEnter:event})"  /></td></tr><tr><td  align="left"><table class="t18ButtonAlternative1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"  summary="">\n<tr>\n<td class="t18L"><img src="/i/themes/theme_18/button_alt1_l.gif" alt="" width="11" height="18" /></td>\n<td class="t18C"><a href="javascript:apex.submit(%7Brequest:&#x27;LOGIN&#x27;%7D);">Login</a></td>\n<td class="t18R"><img src="/i/themes/theme_18/button_alt1_r.gif" alt="" width="11" height="18" /></td>\n</tr>\n</table>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></div>\r\n</td>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td valign="top" align="left" ><div></div><div><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="" id="t18PageFooter" width="100%" style="clear:both">\r\n<tr>\r\n<td id="t18Left" valign="top"></td>\r\n<td id="t18Center" valign="top"></td>\r\n                <div class="coronaBanner">\r\n  <div class="coronaBanner__content">\r\n      <strong>HAVE QUESTIONS ABOUT CORONAVIRUS? VISIT SOUTH AFRICA\xe2\x80\x99S OFFICIAL COVID-19 RESOURCE HERE:<br>\r\n      <a href="https://sacoronavirus.co.za/">https://sacoronavirus.co.za/</a></strong><br><br>\r\n    <a class="coronaBanner__websiteLink" href="https://sacoronavirus.co.za/" rel="noopener nofollow" title="SAcoronavirus.co.za">\r\n      <img class="coronaBanner__websiteLinkImg" border="0" />\r\n    </a><br><br>\r\n    <a class="coronaBanner__hotlineLink" href="tel:+27800029999">\r\n      <strong>Emergency Hotline: 0800 029 999</strong>\r\n    </a><br>\r\n    <a class="coronaBanner__whatsappLink" href="https://wa.me/27600123456?text=Hi" rel="noopener nofollow">\r\n      <strong>WhatsApp Support Line: 0600-123456</strong>\r\n    </a>\r\n  </div>\r\n</div>\r\n<td id="t18Right" valign="top"><span id="t18Customize"></span><br /></td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</table></div></td>\r\n<td class="t18PageRight"><br /></td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n</tr>\r\n</table>\r\n<br class="t18Break"/>\r\n<input type="hidden" id="pPageFormRegionChecksums" value="&#x5B;&#x5D;">\n<input type="hidden" id="pPageItemsRowVersion" value="" /><input type="hidden" id="pPageItemsProtected" value="CpJ-L5-9OTxTAYpkj4TifA" /></form> \r\n\r\n\r\n\n\n\n\n\n<script type="text/javascript">\napex.jQuery( function() {\napex.page.init( this, function() {\napex.jQuery.when.apply( apex.jQuery, apex.page.loadingDeferreds ).done(function() {\ntry {\n(function(){\nvar lTimeoutField = document.getElementById("apex_login_throttle_sec"),\n    lTimeout      = lTimeoutField ? +lTimeoutField.innerHTML : 0;\nif (lTimeout) {\n    var lTimer = window.setInterval (\n        function() {\n            if (lTimeout > 0) {\n                lTimeoutField.innerHTML = lTimeout;\n                lTimeout--;\n            } else {\n                window.clearInterval(lTimer);\n                var lDiv = document.getElementById("apex_login_throttle_div");\n                if (lDiv) {\n                    lDiv.parentNode.removeChild(lDiv);\n                    return true;\n                }\n            }\n        },\n        1000 );\n}})();\n\n\napex.item( \'P101_USERNAME\' ).setFocus();\n} finally {\napex.event.trigger(apex.gPageContext$,\'apexreadyend\');\n}\n});\n});\n});</script>\n\r\n</body>\r\n</html>'
    print (response.text)
    #return nothing
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content ,"html5lib") #returns nothing
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text ,"html5lib") #returns nothing
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content ,"html.parser") #returns nothing
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text ,"html.parser") #returns nothing
```

The strange thing is this works fine on my local environment (python 3.7 and even python 2.7), but not on the server I am using, which uses python 3.5.

How can I correctly decode the response for bs4?

Comment: Not sure, but can you try giving user-agents in headers?

Comment: what about parsing `response.content.decode()`?

Comment: @shivank98, added, but no difference

Comment: @IonutTicus, nice idea, but also no difference

Comment: Can you post the URL or full body?

Comment: Hmm. seems interesting. also, try to update to your user-agent which will now have edge also in it. http://www.useragentstring.com/index.php?id=19940

Comment: Were you able to check the solutions? Do you still have the issue?

Comment: @IonutTicus I had to create a virtual python 2.7 env on the server to get it to work, as I just couldn’t get it to work with 3.5. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: For cases like this I usually just create a docker container with the newer Python version which works correctly so as to not mess with the OS installed python.

Comment: @IonutTicus time for me to learn about docker I guess

Comment: Added a Dockerfile to get you started; Docker can be useful when messing with system packages creates more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not reproduce your error using a Docker container running Python `3.5.9`:

```py
#test.py
import requests
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += 'HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'
try:
    requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.DEFAULT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST += 'HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'
except AttributeError:
    # no pyopenssl support used / needed / available
    pass

logurl = 'https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=pwfone:login'
response = requests.get(logurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content ,"html.parser")
div = soup.find("div", class_="coronaBanner__content")
print(div)
```

Output:

```
<div class="coronaBanner__content">
<strong>HAVE QUESTIONS ABOUT CORONAVIRUS? VISIT SOUTH AFRICA’S OFFICIAL COVID-19 RESOURCE HERE:<br/>
...
```

Versions used:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.9.0
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.9
requests==2.23.0
soupsieve==2.0
urllib3==1.25.9
```

Here is a **Dockerfile** for **3.7** to get you started (use an empty folder and put there `Dockerfile`, `requirements.txt` and `test.py`:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster
COPY /requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

requirements.txt

```
beautifulsoup4
requests
```

To use:

```
docker build -t test .
docker run test
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can explain little what you did and why it's not working for him.

Comment: Did not do anything special; the SSL part is only to allow for some older ciphers which aren't enabled by default in Debian Buster. I'm guessing his error is due to some versions issue - that's why I posted my versions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the `accept-encoding` on the headers.
The following works for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

logurl = 'https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=pwfone:login'
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    response = s.get(logurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content ,"html5lib")
    all_images = soup.find_all("img")
    for img in all_images:
        print(img['src'])
```

---

```
/i/themes/theme_18/button_alt1_l.gif
/i/themes/theme_18/button_alt1_r.gif
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/bfff706703)